# How to run a few lines of script asynchronously in python

Tags: python

I have a scenario wherein i use python with cgi to get certain details from the user and then send the form to the python script which performs certain backend task and returns. Since the task takes considerable amount of time, i would like to run the task asynchronously and in the mean, time send a response page, which says "task in progress. Status will be sent out via mail". Now how to run the task asynchronously?

Comment: You'd need to describe more about the environment and what attempts you've made so far... This is somewhat broad at the moment... It could be as simple as using AJAX or go onto "use an async framework/library"

Comment: I think You should consider using of queue ( for example Celery http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: @JonClements
I have tried Popen function which works pretty well, but how to pass values of string variables to the Popen method?